# Loop through worksheets and insert a formula based on the worksheets name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through worksheets and insert a formula based on the worksheets name. The below code just loops through but only on the first worksheet.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim strFormulas As Variant
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    For Each wsSheet In Worksheets
         If wsSheet.Name = "Maintenance Formatting" Or _
              wsSheet.Name = "Fuel Formatting" Then
              strFormulas1 = "=VLOOKUP(C2,[BillingReportMacros.xlsm]Sheet1!$G:$J,4,FALSE)"
              Lastrow = Range("F1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

              Range("A2").Formula = strFormulas1
              Range("A2:A" & Lastrow).FillDown
         End If
    Next wsSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: So Sheet1 should be replaced? You declare strFormulas but then use strFormulas1. Use Option Explicit!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the code in your loop does not reference a sheet, so will only ever apply to the active sheet by default. And this never changes.

If the sheet reference is in the wrong place, perhaps you can work out how to correct it.

Also, if you are dealing with more than one open workbook, you should add workbook references as well as worksheet ones.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim strFormulas As String
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    For Each wsSheet In Worksheets
        If wsSheet.Name = "Maintenance Formatting" Or wsSheet.Name = "Fuel Formatting" Then
            strFormulas = "=VLOOKUP(C2,[BillingReportMacros.xlsm]'" & wsSheet.Name & "'!$G:$J,4,FALSE)"
            Lastrow = wsSheet.Range("F1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
            wsSheet.Range("A2:A" & Lastrow).Formula = strFormulas
        End If
    Next wsSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm a noob with vba.

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you very much. What would an Elseif look like if I wanted to add another formula that I want to apply to a certain worksheet? Like this?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. If this a separate question, perhaps you accept this answer and ask a new question. If not, perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. And my wording was horrible, apologies.